# Your device does not support vt-x

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

I am beginning to learn android development and using Oracle VirtualBox Machine for setting up the environment to develop.

I have installed the Android Studio, but when I try to create a Virtual Device after clicking on the `AVD Manager` and selecting the Virtual Device, I get an error that says - `Your CPU does not support vt-x`

I have checked in the settings of the `Oracle Virtual Box Machine` and it is enabled there as shown below:

[image]

Also, my system supports the Virtualisation as identified below by Intel Utility:

[image]

Please help, I am stuck at this point and can't continue my learning.

Comment: The error is quite clear: your *CPU* doesn't support it. It doesn't help if you change settings in a program if your *hardware* cannot do it. Maybe you need to disable it.

Comment: My CPU supports it. I have edited the question to show a report.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (today) is that *VirtualBox* **does not support running AVD inside a VM**. Of course, this is of course a serious failure from the VB producers/developers side, because this is what most sane Android developers would want to do.

So for the normal android developer this is a complicated (technical) issue that is very poorly documented and explained. Rightly the settings screenshot in OP make you believe that it should work. But scouring the VB forums, you will only find [rude and misleading answers](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=82357&p=392656#p392656), asking users to [RTFM chapter 10.4](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#gimproviders) which is supposed to describe what is possible. However, and unfortunately, this is written in incomprehensible technical jargon/terms.

But apparently `VMWare` does allow for better virtualization that is compatible with AS, as briefly mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467156/1147688). But other posts, say that newer versions of AS doesn't support that either. So apparently we can't blame it all on the VM producers, but also on Google for stopping to support these technologies.

One may wonder why bother with any VM, if you can't run the most common tools on it. Which by far would be AS.

Comment: I managed to have it working with the "virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-RVI option" of VMware. However, it is slow as hell, and I had to use an old phone with an old API to have it working